Bozza 12 Etudes-Caprices misprints?
I have the Leduc version of this collection. There's a few obvious misprints in the first couple of pieces -- accidentals missing or present when they shouldn't.  My question is about a couple bars in the third etude.
The progression looks and sounds "off" to me. I suspect the C that I marked as C-natural is a misprint, but I can't make head or tail of the final two beats.  Can anyone provide guidance, either from other editions or via chord-theory analysis?
"EDIT"   FWIW the key sig in this section is 3 sharps, treble clef.

There's nothing wrong with that C-sharp, but if you don't like it you can just play C-natural. Same for the last G-natural: it's a very interesting choice of note, but maybe F-natural was intended. Take your pick.

Please give enough of a screenshot to provide the key signature, or say what it is. Might be nice, also, for those unfamiliar to say what instrument this is for, though it shouldn't have any bearing on the question. But the publication history of the work might.

@PiedPiper  thanks but that doesn't really address the issue. Unless there's a clear chord progression which keeps the lower C sharped but not the following upper C,  it looks to me like a misprint.

The rest of the piece is harmonically very simple, so I have to agree with you that C-natural make more sense, and F-natural at the end. But it's only an etude, it doesn't matter what notes you choose. Unless, of course, you're writing a dissertation on the piece.

I found a similar (possibly the same) edition at scribd, which does have key signature (specifically, 3 sharps in that section). The in-staff C could theoretically be natural, but considering the nature of the piece the sharp isn't that off, and it could be considered as a final repercussion of the previous passage. What do you mean with "the final two beats"?

@musicamante  yep, that's my edition -- apologies for writing the wrong information.  I edited to correct.

TL;DR
I believe the score is correct as given.
The two measures comprise a chromatically descending progression with accelerating harmonic rhythm (i.e., each successive harmony get two sixteenth-notes less time than the one before).



Harmony
Duration in sixteenth notes




F#7
9


F#o7
7 (including the rest)


Fo7 (i.e., E#7)
5


Eo7 (or G7)
3



The C# can also be heard in the recording linked below, especially if slowed down sufficiently.
Functionally, both measures serve as a prolongation of the F#7 harmony of the preceding and succeeding measures.

Analysis

Three bars before the excerpt shown, the sax arpeggiates a B minor triad.
In the two bars before the excerpt, the sax arpeggiates and ornaments an F#7 chord — i.e., the V7 chord of B minor.
The first two beats plus one sixteenth note of the first excerpted bar continue this F#7 arpeggiation for a total of 9 sixteenths, initiating a pattern in which each successive harmony is shortened by two sixteenths.
In the final three sixteenths of the first excerpted bar, the chord changes from F#7 to F#o7 — a common-tone chord relation. The reason the preceding note is C# rather than C-natural is that the composer doesn't want to give away the upcoming chromatic shift, plus it initiates the harmonic rhythm pattern.
Now that the chromatic shift has begun, the final three sixteenths of the first except bar plus the first three of the of the second bar make up an F#o7 chord. Including the following rest, this is a duration of 7 sixteenth notes.
Since the chromatic shift is now begun, the entirety of beat two, plus the first sixteenth of beat three (5 sixteenths) can be devoted to the next harmony: E#o7 (spelled with an F rather than E#).
The C# and G that conclude the excerpt (plus rest = 3 sixteenths) hint at what would be the following harmony: Eo7 (or Go7, depending on how one chooses to interpret the chord). Finally leading back to F#7 in the measure following the excerpt.


Recorded example
The C# can be heard in the below recording, especially if sufficiently slowed down.




Thanks for the deep research!

@CarlWitthoft It's a really interest excerpt. Fun analysis to do.

I don't know that this is about chords per se so much as transformations. There's a very good case to be made for the natural: we have three "lumps" of notes that, in general, are lowered by a half step each time. This isn't really about one chord leading to another; this is about a single diminished-7th-(ish) chord being slid downward chromatically. And it would certainly fit this motion if the initial notes of each "lump" traced that chromatic line.
But this is only true in the big picture. The final notes of the first two lumps are the same (unless there's another mistake), and the final two notes of the third lump are higher. Similarly, the F in the middle of the lump rises and then falls. So while a C natural would make a lot of sense here, I don't think there's any solid reason to insist on it based only on this data.
Now, if you have reason to think that this edition is not authoritative, and can find something more original, that's another matter. All I can tell so far is that it seems to have been transcribed and arranged for many different instruments, so it might be a challenging hunt.
